# How can I set SSL for all website pages except index page by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I set force SSL for all of my website pages, just for index page I need to set not SSL ( or both of SSL and not SSL )

How can I set it by .htaccess?

Comment: It would be nice to have your existing rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]
```